# Getting a range of dates for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date-range

I would like to get the entries for a range of dates, using PostgreSQL.

For example...

```
beginyear       endyear       name
---------       -------       -----
950             1100          jason
1300            1400          andrew
```

I would like to get all people who lived in 1050. Could someone please help me to write this query.

Answer (score 5):

```
select name
from yourtable
where 1050 between beginyear and endyear;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE beginyear <= 1050 AND 1050 <= endyear
```