# How do i find out a value between two parameters in postgres sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

For example:

```
name | startyear | endyear 
jon    2003       2005
jake   1999       2002
blake  1997       1998
jake   1995       1996
jason  1993       1994
```

Is there a way to return blake?

I want to know who was treasurer between the two terms of jake.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you give a bit more explanation and a few more examples to clarify?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912293/getting-a-range-of-dates-for-postgres-sql/4912317#4912317 Maybe you two are in the same classroom.

Comment: this is a different question because it has a different criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `between`, like:

```
select  yt.name
from    YourTable yt
where   TheYear between yt.startyear and yt.endyear
```

`between` is inclusive, so this would return Blake for TheYear = 97 and 98.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, this is the best suggestion I can give:

```
SELECT name 
FROM your_table
WHERE startyear > (SELECT min(endyear) FROM your_table WHERE name = 'jake')
  AND endyear   < (SELECT max(startyear) FROM your_table WHERE name = 'jake')
```